# You must have a valid Mac Application Certificate to create a Provisioning Profile

Tags: macos, cocoa

I can't create production certificate in Mac Developer Portal. Error is:

You must have a valid Mac Application Certificate to create a Provisioning Profile.

Although I have already created Mac Application Certificate and it is shown as valid. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?...
Delete the cert and any profiles and create new ones.
Also make sure you are signed into the right Apple ID
(if your iTunes store account ID is different, don't have that open at the same time)